# Unescaping RegEx Characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, programming-languages

I'm trying to make a programming language that takes the input code, which uses `String.replace` to slowly translate bits of the new language into JavaScript, adding regex escapes. However, when I finally print out what I have at the end, it keeps the escapes, and will totally mess up the translated code. Here is what I have now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Translating</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function escapeRegExp(str) {
            return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
        }
        var infile = "{{ }}";
        infile = escapeRegExp(infile);
        infile = infile.replace("[", "{");
        infile = infile.replace("]", "}");


        document.write(infile);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The escapeRegExp is the function I'm using to escape the code in the first place. The infile variable will probably be filled by PHP when I am finished, but for now it just has test code.

Comment: Can you add the output and the desired output, so people can see what goes wrong? Currently, your question doesn't contain an actual question.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind in future questions. This is my first Stack Overflow question. Sorry about any mistakes.

Comment: No problem. It was just a hint to make your question better according to [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can edit it in the suggested way to attract more attention if you are not happy with your own answer and want to attract more attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a very simple way to fix this: just use `infile = infile.replace(/\\/g, "");` and it will replace all backslashes with null strings.